# How to list all debuggable applications?

Tags: android, adb

I want to see all the debuggable applications that are installed on my android phone.

Can I know them using adb? If yes, how?

Answer (score 3):

The `packages.list` file is readable on rooted phones only. You can do something like this in an `adb shell`:

```
for p in $(pm list packages | cut -d : -f 2); do (run-as $p id >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo $p); done
```

Answer (score 2):

The 3rd column in the `/data/system/packages.list` has the `debuggable` flag.

So you can do
`adb shell grep " 1 /" /data/system/packages.list` to list all debuggable packages.