# adb shell command to check the apk is debug or release signed?

Tags: android, adb, aapt, dumpsys

How to check if apk is debug or release signed?
Is there any direct adb command to verify apk signature?

Tried the following `dumpsys` and `aapt` commands, but I am not able to find the exact flag

```
adb shell dumpsys package <package name>
aapt dump badging <apk file>
```

How to find out the given apk is debug or release signed? How to know which builds (user, userdebug or eng) we can install this apk?

Comment: to check if an installed app is debuggable see http://stackoverflow.com/a/29054837/1778421

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to check whether the apk is debuggable use the below aapt command.

```
aapt dump badging /path/to/apk | grep -c application-debuggable
```

Outputs 1: Debuggable
Outputs 0: Not Debuggable.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe Google Play installed apps are **not** allowed to be debuggable.

Comment: On Windows, this tool is in %ANDROID_SDK%\build-tools\<version>\aapt.exe

Comment: Not sure if it changed since this answer was posted but trying with the aapt command from SKD 30, it looks like if you see "application-debuggable" in the output, it is a debug app, otherwise a release app.

Answer (score 9):

i've tried a lot of stuff and came upon the following solution:

```
adb shell dumpsys package <package name> | findstr flags
```

if the build is debuggable, the "flags" line will have "DEBUGGABLE" parameter present. If it's not there, the build is not debug

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it works on older devices and specifically devices that do not have aapt installed as is the case on my Android 4.3 custom device.

Comment: Thanks! Please note this works for windows only. For linux you have to use grep to find that particular line

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be confused. Apks usually have `debug` and `release` versions. And `eng`, `userdebug` and `user` build types are used for the whole firmware images.

You can find build information (if properly populated by builder) by using

```
adb shell getprop ro.build.fingerprint
```

Comment: in what way does this command link to the apk/the installed application I want to check? This always returns me the same result, no matter what I have installed

Answer (score 1):

[run-as](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/0c8bf5798f7beedcf7a1781501151d689b88fe98/run-as/run-as.cpp#41) might provide a hint:

```
$ adb shell run-as com.example.foo.bar
run-as: package not debuggable: com.example.foo.bar
```